# How to use regex in java

Tags: java, regex, spring, payment-gateway

I am integrating with hyperpay payment gateway,

they have this regex to check payment status

The regular expression pattern for filtering out this group is:

`/^(000.000.|000.100.1|000.[36]|000.400.[1][12]0)/`

I have tried to consume it as follow:

1- `Pattern.matches("/^(000.000.|000.100.1|000.[36]|000.400.[1][12]0)/",responseCode);`
did not work as I have received 000.100.110 but the value was false.

2- `Pattern.matches("000.000.|000.100.1|000.[36]|000.400.[1][12]0",responseCode);`

did not work as well the result was false.

please what is the correct way to use the regex.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried reading the documentation ;-)  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html  Also, it would help here to have an example input that should match, but isn't matching.

Comment: Please review your question. It seems you have dublicated your text. Also add example data wich you used to apply the mentioned regex pattern.

Comment: My suggestion would be to validate the regex with the test cases in https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 0):

Appreciate that the [`String#matches()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#matches(java.lang.String)) method applies the regex to the entire string input by default.  So you may think of the `^` and `$` operators as being implicitly added around your regex pattern.  Here is a correct usage of your pattern:

```java
String input = "000.100.1";
String pattern = "(?:000.000.|000.100.1|000.[36]|000.400.[1][12]0).*";
if (input.matches(pattern)) {
    System.out.println("MATCH");
}
```

Note that the pattern I used above in the Java code is really equivalent to this:

```
^(?:000.000.|000.100.1|000.[36]|000.400.[1][12]0).*$
```

Comment: OK good point, you seem correct.

Answer (score 0):

The regular expression

```
/^(000.000.|000.100.1|000.[36]|000.400.[1][12]0)/
```

will never match with `000.100.110`

To match `000.100.110` the below changes can be done

```
/^(000.000.|000.100.1[0-9][0-9]|000.[36]|000.400.[1][12]0)/
```

```
// create a REGEX String
String REGEX = "^(000.000.|000.100.1[0-9][0-9]|000.[36]|000.400.[1][12]0)";

// creare the string
// in which you want to search
String actualString
    = "000.100.110";

// compile the regex to create pattern
// using compile() method
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(REGEX);

// get a matcher object from pattern
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(actualString);

// check whether Regex string is
// found in actualString or not
boolean matches = matcher.matches();
```